# How to fixed page size and break page using css

Tags: css, printing

I am Printing my html page on A4 sheet. I have page height and widht in css. page height and width are working properly but never break the page . I have also used page-break-always , page-break-before but not working. How can i fixed the page height and break content into second page.
see my css :-

```
@page 
    {
        size:  A4;   /* auto is the initial value */
        margin: 0mm;  /* this affects the margin in the printer settings */     
    }    

    html
    {
        background-color: #FFFFFF; 
        margin: 0px;  /* this affects the margin on the html before sending to printer */
    }

    body
    {       
        margin: 10mm 10mm 10mm 10mm; /* margin you want for the content */
    }

@media print {
  .pr-page { 
    margin: 2mm;
    width: 210mm;
    height: 297mm;
    border:1px solid #ff0000;
    page-break-after:always !important;
    position:relative;
    display:table;    
  }    
  .pagebreak { page-break-inside: avoid; page-break-before: always;position:relative;display:block; }

  }
```

HTML:-

```
<div class="pr-page" >page 1</div>
<div class="pagebreak"></div>   
<div class="pr-page">page 2</div>
<div class="pagebreak"></div>   
<div class="pr-page">page 3</div>
```

but pages are messed up see screen-shot:-

[image]

see screen-shot page are messed up into another page.